# Running java codes one by one on server-side JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, thread-safety

Let's explain my graduation project then my question.

My graduation project is about compiling java code online.

To compile user's code, I am using java compiler api on background bean class. After compilation is finished .class file is generated on the D:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse directory. Then the progam saves input file that is writed in text area(in JSP) to D:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse directory. After creating input file, the program runs the code by using dos command at runtime and process getInput stream. The getInput stream returns output of the code. If entered code(user's code) creates any output file, output file will be generated also.

We suggest for users that "your code's output file name should be 'output.txt'".

If the user's code creates any output file. "output.txt" file is generated on D:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse directory.Then, the program retrieves 'output.txt' contents to JSP and show the "output" of their codes to users.

Thus far, there is no problem. Problem is starting here. For one user there is no problem but think for 2 users or more. If 2 or more users compile codes at the same time problems will occur because their .class .java and "output.txt" files will be the same file because for all users we creates same name file on D:\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse directory. Maybe for all users, creating files as unique name will help me but it creates another problem. Our project also analyse codes by looking runtime of the codes. This solution[unique name] brings parallel working codes and analysis results will be unfair. Because sometimes 1 code is worked, sometimes 100 code is worked on the website.

I need to compile, execute, analyse codes one by one, not parallel.

How can I solve this problem? What a solution can be used for this situation?

Comment: If only you used paragraphs, your question would be a lot easier to read...

Comment: Sorry, I asked in a hurry. If you couldn't understand I can seperate paragraphs?

Comment: Even if you're in a hurry: You should *always* take the time to make the question as easy to understand and answer as possible - especially if you're asking for volunteer's help. If you don't have the time now, postpone to later rather than frustrating those that otherwise would gladly help you.

Answer (score 0):

"Accepting random code from the internet to compile/run it server-side" - this sounds like a particularly bad idea, opening you up for all kinds of nasty attacks. DOS (Denial of Service) being only one of them.

Further, the architecture to externally execute code and share a common well-known file - as you state - makes it impossible to execute more than one of these programs at the same time

Storing this external code in some IDE's directory is another weird thing to me.

In fact, I think that this whole architecture is such a bad idea that I have a hard time suggesting a solution other than to rethink it: If you have a *very* good reason for accepting random code from the internet (other than researching exactly this question), please state it here.

With protest (and the suggestion to not follow this tip) I'd point to the option to just pipe the application's console output (e.g. `System.out`) back to the client instead of that one single wellknown file. At least now you can safely be attacked by many users coming in parallel, without mixing up the replies.

Comment: I didn't said other details,sorry. There is a login system for users and all users will be from university. Also their information is kept so we rely on students, we think that there will be no attack from students. Any other user who is not in the university  can not use the system.

Comment: Storing codes in some IDE's directory was obligation for us because if we try another directory to compile/execute, it gives error.

Comment: I still assume that this is a *particularly bad idea*. You're not even stating the problem that you're trying to solve with this solution - and this solution is not a proper solution to *any* problem other than an *artificial* homework assignment.

Comment: I am stating the problem in fact. My problem is about synchronized code blocks in JSP and it seems that the solution solve my problem. I will research synchronized code blocks in JSP.

Comment: Bad or good, are there any way to compile, execute java codes? Especially, if these codes creates outputs(output file). There is no online compiler that handle codes that generates outptut file in the world.  All of them, just handle normal System.out.println statements. Do you know? I think that this solution(executing codes on the folder) is not GOOD or BAD idea. It is OBLIGATION, I think.

Comment: Well, you might be stuck with your obligation - in that case you're obliged to implement a particularly bad design that you should not learn from for future software projects. Is there a way to compile/execute Java code? Well, you're mentioning the Java Compiler API yourself, thus I didn't expect that you need help there. I'd still suggest to use System.in and System.out - there's probably no value writing either input or output to disk.

Comment: Using System.in and System.out does solve output file problem? I think, no. It is my graduation project and professor gave me this problem. When he gives homework for students, he want that they implement their codes output as output text file. Even if it is a bad design it is a necessity. Sometimes to make different things we may use different design. We aware that this structure is different than traditional solutions. But we have to, we must handle codes that generates output files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with using synchronized block. It is enough for my project.
In project JSP file.

```
  synchronized(this){
//my compilation, running and analysis part is here
}
```

Now, one thread can process this part. It means that, for thousands users all codes are processed one by one. No parallel working codes.